# XPath siblings with two conditions

Tags: html, xml, xpath, xml-parsing

What XPath can I use to select sibling HTML elements at the same time. I've tried different variations of the path below with no success:

```
//table/tbody/tr[@class="info" or @class="body"]
```

The HTML:

```
<html>
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr class="info"></tr>
        <tr class="body"></tr>
        <tr class="info"></tr>
        <tr class="body"></tr>
        <tr class="info"></tr>
        <tr class="body"></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</html>
```

Can I select the "Body" tr AND the "info" tr with a single search? In a perfect world, there would be a parent node that combines both of the sibling nodes and I would just pick that one. I want both nodes selected at once.

Comment: and what's the problem? this should select the rows

Comment: It selects the info row and then the body row in separate selections. iw ant to select them all at once

Comment: What is your desired output?

Comment: I want to search the browser console and have it highlight both table rows at the same time

Comment: It is not clear what you want to achieve. The path `//table/tbody/tr` selects the `tr` elements you have shown, and the predicate `[@class="info" or @class="body"]` seems to be true for all your sample rows so it doesn't change the selection. And XPath just selects nodes, it doesn't group results if that is what you are after.

Comment: What I want is an AND filter instead of an OR filter. Can I select the "Body" tr AND the "info" tr with a single search? In a perfect world, there would be a parent node that combines both of the sibling nodes and I would just pick that one

Comment: Updated the description

Comment: It does exactly what it should. With XPath you get as a result a node set with the desired nodes and the nodes are `tr` elements, so you cannot get other elements. You get what is in the XML document. An AND filter would be empty because the attribute cannot have two different values at the same time. It is written `//table/tbody/tr[@class="info"][@class="body"]`